# Mic Audio Input Visualiztion in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, audio, visualization

I need to create an application that reads mic input and shows it in a waveform visualization. 
I am using the code from here: [channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/NET-Voice-Recorder](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/NET-Voice-Recorder)

I have played around with the code, and have been able to extract code that listens to mic input, extract the recorded volume, and shows on a progress bar. However, showing it as a waveform visualization (i.e. the polygon waveform) is not working. Is there a simple way to do that? Most of the other online articles shows how to plot a .wav file, however I am looking for sth more dynamic, as a continuous stream of input is received by the mic.

Comment: You may tell us what exactly does not work?

Comment: Code has a separate user control, named PolygonWaveFormControl to visualize the waveform. It is not getting integrated well with the mic input. Somehow the properties on PolygonWaveFormControl are not getting called as expected.